# Sum of lists in a series using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns namely 'name' and 'sales' in a dataframe df

| names | sales |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| abc | 2 |
| abc | 3 |
| xyz | 4 |
| xyz | 5 |
| xyz | 6 |

I want to add the sales according to names which should look like this:

| names | sales |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 6 |
| xyz | 15 |

**My code:**

```
groupdf = df.groupby('names')

grouplist = groupdf["names"].apply(list)
```

which gives me a **series**:

```
names  
abc       [1,2,3]

xyz       [4,5,6]
```

I am stuck here and cannot add them further and return a dataframe.
Can anyone help me with a better approach?

Comment: `out=df.groupby('names',as_index=False).sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done. Instead of getting the list of values for each name, you could basically sum all occurences for a given name right after your `groupby`. This is a realy basic way of doing that kind of things in Pandas.

The whole python code will look like :

```py
groupdf = df.groupby('names')
sums_by_names = groupdf.sum()
```